# changing the font color of the sidebar in shiny dashboard

Tags: html, css, shiny

I have literally no html/css experience and hence I solicit your help with the following.

I am using a shiny dashboard with a default sidebar. I tried to change the background color and the font color of the sidebar using the following line of code inside the dashboardBody:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.skin-black .main-sidebar {color: #000000; background-color: #FFB6C1;}')))
```

What happened was that the new sidebar has a background color of #FFB6C1, which I intended to. But the font color in the sidebar didn't change into black and it is still white! Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot
San

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across an example that helped me solving the issue. http://journocode.com/2016/04/04/r-first-web-application-shiny/

Accordingly, the problem was solved by used:

```
label = HTML('<p style="color:black;">Maximum number of suggestions</p>')
```

in order to depict the color of the label in black instead of white color obtained when using only:

```
label = "Maximum number of suggestions"
```

Of course both were arguments of the selectInput object.

Thanks KH for the help and of course thanks MARIE-LOUISE TIMCKE for your amazing post.

Ciao

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector may not be targeting text elements, rather a sidebar div. Assuming your text elements are under the .main-sidebar class, this should/may work. Just replace ELEMENT with whatever HTML tag your text is enclused in, like

```
.skin-black .main-sidebar ELEMENT {
color: #000000;

.skin-black .main-sidebar {
background-color: #FFB6C1;
}
```

Whitespace does not matter.

Comment: Hi KY, thanks for the suggestions. Your post is helping me be more specific now. I want to change the font color of the label of a selectInput element in the sidebar. I tried `.skin-black .main-sidebar selectInput_id { color: #000000; } but it didn't work. What of you think?

Comment: Ok, let me add another layer of specificity: what I want is to change the font color of the label of a selectInput in sidebarMenu in the dashboardSidebar. It seems that I am confused with where to place the .skin-black .main-sidebar ELEMENT {color: #000000;} and also how to refer to the ELEMENT? Should i refer to the ELEMENT using the selectInput id?

Comment: My suggestion is, just add a class unique to the element(s) containing your text, then use ONLY that class to change the color. Providing HTML codr would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks KH for the followup: I tried each one of the following lines with no success so far: tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.skin-black .main-sidebar sidebarMenu {color: #000000;}')))
                tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.skin-black .main-sidebar selectInputid {color: #000000;}')))

Comment: I am also confused about the location where I should insert these any of these lines. How can I make it specific to change the color of the label of the specific selectInput is also another point of confusion.

Comment: Please just provide the HTML code you're using, and I'll tell you what to do

Comment: this is what I exactly tried to use, thanks a lot KH

Comment: tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.skin-black .main-sidebar sidebarMenu {color: #000000;}'))) tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.skin-black .main-sidebar selectInputid {color: #000000;}')))

Comment: I asked for the HTML, not your CSS

Comment: Excuse my ignorance of both html and css. I hope this is what you are asking for:

Comment: <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
            <label class="control-label" for="NoOfPred">Maximum number of suggestions</label>
            <div>
              <select id="NoOfPred"><option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3" selected>3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option></select>
              <script type="application/json" data-for="NoOfPred" data-nonempty="">{}</script>
            </div>
          </div>

Comment: I want to change the color of >Maximum number of suggestions</ from white to black? How can i do the ui of the shiny app?

Comment: I would just use "label{color:black}". Now, if you had other forms in a pagr you wanted to change the color of, just add some specificity, like ".otherform label{}"

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Kasper's answer, but to directly embed into shiny code:

```
 dashboardBody(
      tags$head(        
        #in line styling
        tags$style(HTML(

        #siderbar background
        '.skin-blue .main-sidebar {
          background-color: white;}',

        #siderbar text color
        '.skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar{
          color: #red;}'
        )
       )
      )
```

Note that

1. although it changes the style of sidebar, the code is within dashboardBody().
2. depending on your current dashboard skin color, you need to change the ".skin-blue" (blue is default) to e.g. ".skin-black" as needed
3. for changing font color, it is essential to have ".sidebar" after ".main-sidebar". ".sidebar" basically is the ELEMENT mentioned by @Kasper. (To locate such elements, use Developer tools in your chrome browser, and inspect everything until you can locate the precise block of html code, and use the ELEMENTs after "class=" for this purpose.)